# Is Dry Cabinet necessary for both a Point and Shoot Camera & a DSLR Camera?

Tags: dslr, point-and-shoot, equipment-storage

Is Dry Cabinet better or a Dry Box? and is it necessary for (a) A Point and Shoot Camera (b) a DSLR Camera?

Comment: For what kind of storage? Long term or short term? Portable?

Comment: Was wondering if it is necessary to have a Dry Cabinet for (a) a point and shoot camera (b) DSLR Camera. Portable & non-Portable is quite ok since I lived in near the equator.

Comment: Necessary *for what*? Understanding your requirements helps us give better answers.

Answer (score 7):

**Not usually but it probably depends on where you live.**

The maximum storage humidity of cameras is relatively high but I do take extra caution while in tropical rain forests which I'm kind of far from right now. I own several cameras and dozens of lenses, some of them do not get use for months and even years at a time and never had any problem despite the climate changing here significantly and get quite humid.

For long term storage, I keep the cameras in their original cardboard boxes with silica pouches. They change colors when too humid and all you need it to but them in a dry frying pan for a few minutes to get them back to normal.

Comment: I find that frying cameras tends to ruin their functionality :-).